# How to read data from cloudformation instance and display it in Outputs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm creating cloudformation script to create one instance. After launch I want to read data of a file and display it in Outputs.

I have tried using `Fn::Join` and `Fn::Sub` but no luck.

```
"Outputs" : {
         "FileData" : {
            "Value" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [{ "Fn::Sub": "cat /opt/tmp/data"} ]]},
            "Description" : "Read file data"
         }
```

and

```
"Outputs" : {
         "FileData" : {
            "Value" : { "Fn::Sub": "cat /opt/tmp/data"},
            "Description" : "Read file data"
         }
```

I want content of the file like

```
"Outputs": [
                {
                    "Description": "Read file data",
                    "OutputKey": "FileData",
                    "OutputValue": "<content>"
                }
            ]
```

But I'm getting

```
"Outputs": [
                {
                    "Description": "Read file data",
                    "OutputKey": "FileData",
                    "OutputValue": "cat /opt/tmp/data"
                }
            ]
```

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do this, other than perhaps to create a custom resource with custom code that cats the relevant file and returns it as an output. A better option might be for the EC2 launch userdata to copy the file to a known location in S3 e.g. s3://mybucket/<instanceid>

Comment: What do you mean display in Outputs? Do you mean you want display the content of a file in the output section of CF stack and use it from another stack? Can you please elaborate on your intent? How do you plan to use the content of that tmp file? There might be a better ways to accomplish that.

Comment: @SaeedD.The file contains one-liner string and this is the password. However, I'm able to get the public IP of the instance. If anyhow I get that line from the file, I can save my work of SSH into the instance and read the file manually.

Answer (score 0):

> As of now, AWS CloudFormation takes care of provisioning and configuring the resources for you.

So, it would NOT be possible to accomplish the use-case (cat a file from EC2 in Outputs section) via CloudFormation.